# Saving DWT files as HTML doesn't seem to work properly?

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I'm somewhat of a new user to Adobe Dreamweaver and I have a question relating to it. 
This may be somewhat of a weird question but I'm stumped about this issue.

I'm creating a website for a group and I'm editing the site through a template (.dwt) and every time I save as a .html file and edit from it, there is a weird pop-up asking "Save As Template" and reverts my .html file back to .dwt file.

I've tried copy the content in the .dwt file onto a notepad and save as .html, and then I tried opening it up on Dreamweaver and edit... but still same problem occurs.

Is there a way to save .dwt file to .html and edit and save it AS .html without reverting my save back to .dwt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very clear as to what you're actually trying to accomplish.

If you are trying to create a new page based on your template file, then you can use the File -> New... -> Page from template. If you're trying to save the contents of your Dreamweaver template out as "plain" HTML, then you will have to remove the template code within the page, which is nothing more than HTML comments, such as:

Remove all of the HTML comments manually similar to above in your DWT file, and then do a save as to get a "plain" HTML file.

If you have a child page that you want to detach from its parent template you can go to: Modify -> Templates -> Detach from template.